# Running virtualenv'd Python script in OSX does not find packages

Tags: python, macos, virtualenv, supervisord

My supervisord.conf like this:

```
[program:py_in_virtual_env]
command=/path/to/virtualenv/bin/python my_python_script.py
```

It works on centOS, but it does not work on Mac os, I have tried to change the command to below:

```
command=start.sh
```

start.sh like this:

```
source /path/to/virtualenv/bin/activate
/path/to/virtualenv/bin/python my_python_script.py
```

It doesn't work.

Then try to add environment in supervisord.conf

```
environment=PATH="/path/to/virtualenv/bin"
```

It still can not work on Mac OS.

what sholud I do?

Comment: In what way it does not work? What does the supervisor log say?

Comment: It can not import the packages which are installed in the virtualenv by pip

Comment: `command=/path/to/virtualenv/bin/python my_python_script.py` is correct and there is no reason why it would not work on OSX as far as I see. If there is any doubt you can always do `import sys ; print(sys.path)` or similar in Python application to confirm what the active virtualenv is.

Comment: I have seen the sys.path, which is corrrect. I don't konw why.

Comment: I found some packages are in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages. I used `pip install XXX` in virtualenv.